# Convert an Array of Bytes to Persian string

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I have string like "062A0633062A0020" and I want to convert it to a suitable farsi string. How can I do it? (unicode to iran system encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .Net Frameowrk Library (System.Text):

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}


byte[] a = StringToByteArray("062A0633062A0020");
char[] c = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetChars(a); // تست
```